# Typescript union type to object type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to translate a type of this kind:

```
export type UnionType = {
    element:
        | { $case: 'a'; a: number }
        | { $case: 'b'; b: string }
        | { $case: 'c'; c: boolean };
};
```

to a type of a kind:

```
type OneOfConverter<T> = any; // TODO

type ObjectType = OneOfConverter<UnionType>;

// type ObjectType = {
//     a: number;
//     b: string;
//     c: boolean;
// };
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqA7AlhDAVZVAXjgG8BYAKDhrmABtgBbYDGALitu7gB8y4AEgDGAQwDOwdnADkomQG44o6RgCuTAEbAocAL5ceNfqSFjJ0mZsVxN08TChYMAc32GjJsxKmzhN4WlNCAhGUQx9BSo9KMoqJBQ4AHkMYCSAMwBhXAA3HRgdAB48AD44EnDEJQB6arg8JIARJKp4wmTNACtgYRgCRJIUtKzc-KLMHHxCEtiqWoR2pK6evvaSCkp57hU4dS0dWK3aOzgHJ1dDuu5A2xCwjEvIoA)

Comment: In `{ $case: 'a'; a: number }` do `a` and the value of `$case` hae to be correlated ? Why not `$case` and `type` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir The input type, unfortunately, cannot be changed, it is generated from the `proto` file. And yes `$case: 'a'` correlated with key `a: number`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVg4lm) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please tell me what's missing so I can address it.

Comment: @jcalz incredible, exactly what is needed! thanks! you can post this as an answer :)

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/WoJaMm

Comment: @jcalz was first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion here would be:

```
type OneOfConverter<T extends { element: { $case: PropertyKey } }> = {
    [U in T["element"] as U["$case"]]: U["$case"] extends keyof U ? U[U["$case"]] : never
}
```

It uses [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over the union members of `T['element']` (an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) corresponding to the type of the `element` property of the type `T` passed in) and put each member of that union into a type parameter `U`.  Then the key we want is `U["$case"]`.

For each value we pretty much want to index into `U` with that key, so `U[U["$case"]]`, but the compiler doesn't know if that member really will exist (maybe you pass in `{ $case: "z" }` and the `z` property doesn't appear for some reason).  So we have to address its concern by first doing the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) check `U["$case"] extends keyof U`, which compares the desired key to [the keys of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) `U`.  If it exists, we grab the property value as `U[U["$case"]]`.  If it doesn't, then we return `never` for want of anything better.

Let's make sure it works:

```
type ObjectType = OneOfConverter<UnionType>;
// type ObjectType = {
//     a: number;
//     b: string;
//     c: boolean;
// };
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqA7AlhDAVZVAXjgG8BYAKDhrmABtgBbYDGALitrgB8y4AJAGMAhgGdg7OAHIR0gNxwRUjAFcmAI2BQ4AXy60+pQaIlTpGhXA1SxMKFgwBzPQZpGT4yTKFWhUjQgIRhEMPXkqXQjKKiQUOAB5DGAEgDMAYVwAN20YbQAePDoQPIwAEzF+BmZWDn5hLykABSgIFFhEAGlgRD09AD44EgpqWgBtNDhHODwxgCJqljY5gF0lSrR5holVlalNue3gVeLSirgAax6IVPQ4AH50Ca3TY5W1lWAcqEiqWMJEhoAFbAIQwAjxEhJFIZbK5AqYHD4Qj9aIAejRCABCWBoPBAOGVAx3CUKnUWig6Mx3BscDsDmcVJJ-msQRCGCZUSAA)